# Change the Text of Xaml in vb code

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

so I am creating a simple number guessing game application for Windows Phone 8, I am new to phone app development and xaml. I have used vb.net for a number of months and am familer with the language so I chose to develop my app using vb.

The problem I am having is when im trying to update the text property of a xaml textblock from my vb code. Here is the code for my xaml textblock:

`<TextBlock Name="txb_HigherLower"
                       Text=""
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />`

I have a button that when clicked tests the users input and should change the text property of the xaml element, here is the vb code.

```
If txt_Guess.Text = FirstRandomNumber Then
        btn_Guess.Content = "Horray!"
    ElseIf txt_Guess.Text > FirstRandomNumber Then
        txb_HigherLower.Text = "You guessed too high! Try Again!"
    Else
        txb_HigherLower.Text = "You guessed too low! Try Again!"
    End If
```

When I run the app I get an error,

Error: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Number Guessing Game.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Edit: Here is the XAML around my textblock:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBox Name="txt_Guess"
                 Width="Auto"
                 Height="Auto"
                 ></TextBox>
        <Button Name="btn_Guess" 
                Background="Orange"
                Width="Auto"
                Height="Auto"
                Click="Guess_Click">Guess!</Button>
        <TextBlock Name="txb_HigherLower"
                   Text=""
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Your TextBox's name is `txb_HigherLower` so what's txt_Guess ?? + Are you sure you didn't delete that `StaticResource` PhoneTextNormalStyle ?

Comment: find out which object/property is null. see inner exception (click on "view detail" in exception message box). And in which line exactly you got that exception?

Comment: No txb is my text block, i also have a textbox which the user enters their guess.

Comment: When I click on view detail I get this: {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Number_Guessing_Game.MainPage.Guess_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)     at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()     at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()     at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.<OnMouseLeftButtonUp>b__3()}

Comment: I get the exception in either the lines that try to change the text, it differes depending on the random number.

Comment: hmm.. I don't think that is the problem. You can try to put this line in constructor method : `txb_HigherLower.Text = "Test"` and that should change textblock's text fine

Comment: I tried putting that line in the constructor and got the same error.

Comment: ok, that confirmed the problem, and my assumption was wrong. where you put definition of `txb_HigherLower` in XAML? try to post more of your XAML around the textbox (put it in question, not in comment), so we can see if anything wrong there

Comment: After restarting the emulator completely its now working, must have been a bug. Thanks for the help.